# Unix Commands removing duplicate names

Tags: unix

Suppose that file1, file2, file3, file4, and file5x each contain a list of new usernames to be added to the system, but you only have time to add the first 50 users and you need to remove duplicate usernames and save the results to a file named usernames.  What would be the UNIX command to do this?

Comment: `cat file1 file2 file3 | uniq > usernames`

Comment: `cat f1 <(echo) f2 <(echo) f3 <(echo) | sort | uniq > usernames` the `sort` is necessary as `uniq` only filters out adjacent duplicates.

Comment: `cat file* | sort -u`

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
cat file1 file2 .... fileNN | sort -u
```

Comment: Or `cat file[1-5]` for this case.